# Identifying Broad-Leaf Plant/Weed

Tags: identification

I'm in the process of systematically removing all the weeds from my backyard -- starting with dandelions and thistle. All of a sudden, this thing sprouted in the middle of a bare patch. What on earth is it?

If it helps, I live in southern Ontario, near Toronto.

[image]

Comment: looks awfully familiar but I can only say that it is not burdock or sow thistle.

Comment: Whether it's a teazel or not it's a weed.  Remove it and be sure to get the root!

Comment: How do you know it's a weed?

Comment: A weed is just a plant in the wrong place.  If it's not grass or clover and it's in your lawn then it's a weed for you.

Comment: You can also wait for flowers, to see if it is a teazel or not. I am curious too :)

Comment: Yeah, I think I might do just that.

Comment: Given that teazel is biennial, you may need to wait a year to see flowers.

Comment: I might just wait until fall and then uproot it. I want a simple grass lawn, no funky stuff yet. Current phase is de-weeding.

Comment: Did you ever grow this long enough to flower? I'm curious because that seems to have been the deciding factor for making the identification. Now that the question has been brought forward with a new answer, it would be extra helpful. It sounds like your last plan might have been to get rid of it before waiting another year to see the flowers, so if that's what you did, nevermind!!!

Comment: @Sue sorry, I did indeed yank it out (or chop it down) before it flowered. Next time, I'll wait and take pictures first ...

Answer (score 4):

It's certainly teasel if it has a row of thorns along the underside spine of the leaf.

It's a dynamic accumulator, with a deep tap root. It pierces clay soils and brings up important micronutrients. The leaves are good for mulching. It collects water at the base of its leaves. It will mature with a distinctive spiky seed pod that crafters work into arrangements when dried. Goats love it.

As with most weeds, it's trying to tell you something. If it's not right where you want something else, I'd let it grow until **before** it goes to seed, then cut it down and spread the leaves out on your fall/winter beds for mulch. As a mulch, it will reduce erosion while putting into surface soil minerals and micro-nutrients that it probably lacks.

Either that, or feed it to someone's goat! As weeds go, it's a pretty nice one. :-)

Answer (score 3):

This looks like some [Teazel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dipsacus) to me.

**Update 2012-05-31**: I made a photo of young [Fuller's teasel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dipsacus_fullonum) plants growing near my home:

[image]

Now I am quite sure your plant is the same or other plant from the Dipsacaceae (teazel) genus. Notice the thorns on the lower side of the leaves. I can see them on your photo too.

Comment: Doesn't look like it to me. Doesn't even have the flowers.

Comment: Most plants are leaves-only before the flowers appear. These look like leaves of a teazel plant to me. I may be wrong, though.

Comment: This website has a better picture of teasel leaves and they are close in their resemblance but seem to lack the toothed edges on the plant http://www.ppws.vt.edu/scott/weed_id/diwsi.htm

Comment: They don't seem prickly either. Hmm. It is still a distinct possibility.

Answer (score 2):

Dipsacus fullonum, I'm pretty sure and I agree with Jacek.

In your picture the plant is still very young, it takes a couple of months to see the flowers. In Italy it is very common and it is called **cardo dei lanaioli**

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is some kind of Dock/Sorrel - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rumex

So, maybe not a weed, but an edible plant.

I think we will be more lucky in identifying the plant if you let it flower, and then upload a new picture.